# Is using a db40 database in an android application a good idea?

Tags: android, database, db4o

Does anyone see any issues with using db40 object database in android?

[db4o.com](http://db4o.com)

I just want it to store some data for me locally on the device, and it is a really simple easy to use object databse.

- Will it work on android?
- Is there possibly a better/simpler / more standard way to go?

I want it to store a list of users devices.

Comment: Try it. The standard way is [`SQLite`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) since that is present on every device and has a built-in API, adding an ORM layer (e.g. [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml), [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/)) on top would be the standardiest way of "object" database.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no any issue in that. We are using it for one of our application.
Even in latest version they have made its foot print very small. Means taking small amount of heap memory when you open it.

Comment: But do you have to include the 40mb jar for it to work? If thats the case sqllite might be better

Comment: No I think by mistake you refer wrong jar. Its just 1.20 MB(db4o-7.4.88.12908-java5.jar)

Comment: Was jsut he downlaod folder that was 40mb